# Need help with onClick and intents

Tags: android

I'm working and an app based on the Notepad tutorial...In the tutorial you click on a note in the listview and you are taken to edit were the corresponding information is shown, you then make your changes select confirm..and are taken back to Main.

I added a second activity to the app "contact" now when you click on a note in the listview and you are taken to contact were the corresponding information is shown including a button............ you click the button and are taken to edit.........And this is were my problem pops its ugly head. When i ckick the button a get a blank screen and a forced close popup........

Here is the code from the main taking you to contact....This works the information is shown

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}
```

Here is the code that takes you from contact to edit.....This gives me the error, I'm sure it has to do with "intent.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);" needing to be recoded to work with a onClick compared to a onListitemClick........I'm thinking the id is not being passed over

```
public void onClick(View v) {
String id = null;
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.admin: // doStuff
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivity(intent); 
    break;
```

Could someone show me how to do this from a button????

Here is the code from Main, Contacts and Edit..........If you need it .......Thanks

Main.class

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;

private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private static final int ABOUT = Menu.FIRST + 2;
private static final int TESTBUTTON = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int CONTACT_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
private static final int CANCEL_ID = Menu.FIRST + 5;

private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
    String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME, NotesDbAdapter.KEY_RANK};


    // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2};

    // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mainlistrow, notesCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    menu.add(0, ABOUT, 0, R.string.menu_about);
    menu.add(0, TESTBUTTON, 0, R.string.menu_test);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createNote();
            return true;
        case ABOUT:        
            menuabout();        
            return true;
        case TESTBUTTON:        
            menutest();        
            return true;    
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, CONTACT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_contact);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    menu.add(0, CANCEL_ID, 0, R.string.menu_cancel);

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
        case CONTACT_ID:
            contact();
            return true;   
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void menutest() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Newmain.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    Log.i(this.toString(), "menu test");
}

private void contact() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
    Log.i(this.toString(), "menu contact");
}    

private void createNote() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Admin.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

public void menuabout() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);
    dialog.setTitle("About NCO Leaders Book");      
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.AboutButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
              });
              //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
              dialog.show();
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
    i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
```

}

Contact.class

```
    public class Contact extends Activity implements OnClickListener{    
    private EditText mNameText;
    private EditText mRankText;
    private Long mRowId;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);

        Button adminButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.admin);
        adminButton.setOnClickListener(this); 

        mNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mRankText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rank);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
            (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                    : null;}

          populateFields();
    };


private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchsoldiers(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mNameText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        mRankText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_RANK)));
    }
}

//@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String id = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.admin: // doStuff
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Edit.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.i("Onclick", "EndingTestNext");    
        break;
}}

}
```

Edit.class

```
public class Edit extends Activity {

private EditText mNameText;
private EditText mRankText;
private EditText mSsnText;
private Long mRowId;
private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    setContentView(R.layout.edit);
    setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

    mNameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    mRankText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rank);
    mSsnText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ssn);

    Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);


    mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
        (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
    if (mRowId == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                                : null;
    }

    populateFields();

    confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }

    });
}

private void populateFields() {
    if (mRowId != null) {
        Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
        startManagingCursor(note);
        mNameText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        mRankText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_RANK)));
        mSsnText.setText(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_SSN)));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    populateFields();
}

private void saveState() {
    String name = mNameText.getText().toString();
    String rank = mRankText.getText().toString();
    String ssn = mSsnText.getText().toString();

    if (mRowId == null) {
        long id = mDbHelper.createNote(name, rank, ssn);
        if (id > 0) {
            mRowId = id;
        }
    } else {
        mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, name, rank, ssn);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on. The Contact class expects that the Intent that starts it should have a Long extra under the KEY_ROWID key. In your onClick method, you are setting a *String* null value. When Contact.onCreate tries to retrieve it, it is getting an explicit null String value, which can't be assigned to the Long mRowId variable. Just don't call putExtra, since you don't actually have any data to pass.

Comment: I think he still needs to call putExtra with the rowid that he is viewing in the Contact view, so he can edit it in the Edit intent.

Comment: That's probably what OP wants to happen. However, it's not wrong to not call putExtra. A null (or missing) rowid creates a new note. (See `Edit.saveState()`.) The thing to **not** do is to store a `String` object (null or otherwise) under KEY_ROWID.

Comment: Ted Hopp - Your correct I'm not wanting to pass data to the edit class, i need to go to the edit class and have in show the records from person shown on the contacts class.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code, that works, the `id` in onListItemClick() is a numeric row id which is used in your database as KEY_ROWID. That's why it's passed as extra data.  In your switch to using a button and OnClick() the button code only has the view(of the Contact), not the rowid that you're editing. So you want to make sure you pass the row id into the Contact intent somehow, so that the button click OnClick() can pass that rowid into the Edit class as the `id` value. You can't just set it to null, as you did. It really need to be the row id from the database that you are viewing, so your button can call the Edit class

Comment: codeboy2k - I agree "pass the row id into the Contact intent somehow" that's the part that's driving me nuts HOW?

Comment: It looks like your main class onListItemClick() is already sending the rowid into the Contact class. You just need to extract that rowid from the Intent that started the Contact activity, and pass it into the Edit activity through the intent that starts Edit.  In the button's onClick() of the Contact class, use this.getIntent() to get the intent that started the Contact activity. Then use getExtras() to get a map (a bundle type) to retrieve the original rowid. Put that rowid into the new intent used to start your Edit activity.

Comment: codeboy2k = Are you talking about using something like this                       Bundle extras  = getIntent().getExtras();